# Matlab: calculate differences between datetime arrays in fractional seconds

Tags: matlab, datetime

I'm reading in time data with fractional precision (hundredths of seconds):

For every entry in this datetime array, I want to determine the difference with the first entry, in seconds (with fractional precision):

```
times=datetime(myCellArray,'InputFormat','HH:mm:ss.SS');
eventtimes=between(starttime,times(2:end));
```

this returns:

```
eventtimes = 

0h 0m 19.72s
0h 1m 46s
0h 6m 45.9s
0h 6m 53.18s
```

I want to get from here to a regular array simply holding (fractional) seconds:

```
[19.72
106
405.9
413.18]
```

What I've tried so far (split, time), always results is a loss of the fractions.

Comment: Is `eventtimes` a string array?  `between` is a function we don't have access to.

Comment: @rayryeng: "between" is a function available from (at least) Matlab 2014b: [link] (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/between.html), and results in an array of the special "datetime" type (not a string array). If there's another way of getting time differences (retaining fractions), I'm all for it

Comment: Ah sorry. I'm on 2013a. I also did a Google search and ended up with nothing... Which is why I made the comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `eventtimes` is a cell array of strings, you can do this:

```
eventtimes={'0h 0m 19.72s'
    '0h 1m 46s'
    '0h 6m 45.9s'
    '0h 6m 53.18s'};

for i=1:length(eventtimes)
    %// Read each line of data individually
    M(i,:)=sscanf(eventtimes{i},'%d%*s%d%*s%f%*s').';
end

s=(M(:,1)*60+M(:,2))*60+M(:,3) %// Convert into seconds
```

which gives

```
s =
   19.7200
  106.0000
  405.9000
  413.1800
```

Comment: notice that in your answer, `M(:,1) ` should be multiplied by  `3600 ` (see my answer below) rather than by  `24 `

Comment: Oh yes, hours not days!! Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately, eventtimes is not a cell array of strings, but of the (pretty recent?) "calendarDuration" type.

Comment: This is why it helps to include complete code that runs, or at least explain what your problem is, rather than making us guess such important things.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to the answer provided by @David, the last line of code:

```
s=(M(:,1)*24+M(:,2))*60+M(:,3) %// Convert into seconds
```

should be:

```
s=(M(:,1)*60+M(:,2))*60+M(:,3) %// Convert into seconds
```

Since `M(:,1)` contains `hours`, to convert them into seconds, they have to be multiplied by `3600 (60 min. * 60 sec.)`

The expected resuls as described in the question and the ones provided by @David seem correct only because all input have "`0h`".

In case any of the input times last more than 1h, the results will be:

```
0h 0m 19.72s
2h 1m 46s
3h 6m 45.9s
0h 6m 53.18s

s=
   19.72
 7306.00
11205.90
  413.18
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for noticing the mistake, actually I did not check the brackets and I've made the multiplication by using a calculator (my bad). Nevertheless, even counting the brackets, to multiply `M(:,1)` by `24` seems not correct, it has to be multiplied by `60`. I've updated the code in my answer.

Comment: I accept your critic, I deserve it. I can also delete my answer. Nevertheless, please, at least update your answer and fix the bug.

Comment: unfortunately, eventtimes is not a cell array of strings, but of the "calendarDuration" type. It's really the parsing of this variable that's proving to be a headache. In the meantime I've now suggested a solution myself..

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution using etime that bypasses the "between" function and its odd calendarDuration type output:

```
%read in with fractions
times=datetime(myCellArray(:,1),'InputFormat','HH:mm:ss.SS');

%turn into datevectors (uses today's date: works as long as midnight isn't crossed)
timevect=datevec(times);

%separate start time from subsequent times
starttime=timevect(1,:);
othertimes=timevect(2:end,:);

%use etime with repmat of starttime to get differences:
relativetimes=etime(othertimes,repmat(starttime,[size(othertimes,1) 1]));

relativetimes(1:4)

ans =

                 19.72
                   106
                 405.9
                413.18
```